# Javascript callback functions with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I am writing a generic function that will be reused in multiple places in my script.

The function uses ajax (using jQuery library) so I want to somehow pass in a function (or lines of code) into this function to execute when ajax is complete.
I believe this needs to be a callback function, but after reading through a few callback answers I'm still a bit confused about how I would implement in my case.

My current function is:

```
function getNewENumber(parentENumber){

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "get_new_e_number.php",
               data: {project_number: projectNumber, parent_number: parentENumber},
               success: function(returnValue){
                    console.log(returnValue);
                    return returnValue; //with return value excecute code

                },
                error: function(request,error) {
                    alert('An error occurred attempting to get new e-number');
                    // console.log(request, error);
                }
        });
    }
```

With this function I want to be able to do something in the same way other jQuery functions work ie;

```
var parentENumber = E1-3;

getNewENumber(parentENumber, function(){
    alert(//the number that is returned by getNewENumber);
});
```

Comment: I suppose, this is not possible (or at least, very hard) this way. You should swap functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just give `getNewENumber` another parameter for the function, then use that as the callback.

```
   // receive a function -----------------v
function getNewENumber( parentENumber, cb_func ){

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "get_new_e_number.php",
           data: {project_number: projectNumber, parent_number: parentENumber},

             // ------v-------use it as the callback function
           success: cb_func,
            error: function(request,error) {
                alert('An error occurred attempting to get new e-number');
                // console.log(request, error);
            }
    });
}

var parentENumber = E1-3;

getNewENumber(parentENumber, function( returnValue ){
    alert( returnValue );
});
```

Comment: Perfect. I new it would be something simple. It's always easier to learn when it is put in your own context. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[@patrick dw's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988277/javascript-callback-functions-with-ajax/4988294#4988294) is correct. But if you want to keep calling the `console.log` (or any other actions) always, no matter what the caller code function does, then you can add the callback (your new parameter) inside the success function you already have:

```
function getNewENumber(parentENumber, cb_func /* <--new param is here*/){ 

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "get_new_e_number.php",
           data: {project_number: projectNumber, parent_number: parentENumber},
           success: function(returnValue){
                console.log(returnValue);
                cb_func(returnValue); // cb_func is called when returnValue is ready.
            },
            error: function(request,error) {
                alert('An error occurred attempting to get new e-number');
                // console.log(request, error);
            }
    });
}
```

And the calling code remains the same as yours except that the function will receive the returnValue by parameter:

```
var parentENumber = E1-3;

getNewENumber(parentENumber, function(val /* <--new param is here*/){
    alert(val);
});
```

Comment: Yea when I was implementing it in my code I did wonder how to do it if I had wanted to have other success actions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would be better done with jQuery's [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/).  Have your AJAX call *return* the `jqXHR` object.

```
function getNewENumber(parentENumber) {
    return $.ajax( { ... } );
}

getNewENumber(E1 - 3).then(success_callback, error_callback);
```

If you want to keep the error callback *within* that function you can register that there instead:

```
function getNewENumber(parentENumber) {
    var jqXHR = $.ajax( { ... } );
    jqXHR.fail( ... );
    return jqXHR;
}

getNewENumber(E1 - 3).done(success_callback);
```