# Working with JSON arrays and objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have [json data here](https://api.tabanawireless.co.ke/GDdata/timeline.php?com_option=item&item_get_id=1497). I am trying to get data in `property_more_images` like this:

```
getItemImages: function(pid) {
    xhr.simpleCall({
        query:{ 
            com_option:"item",
            item_get_id:pid
        },
        func:'timeline'
    }, function(response) { 
           if (response.err_code === 0) { 
               console.log(response.data[0].property_more_images);

               var arr = response.data[0].property_more_images;

               notice_obj = [];
               for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i) {
                   notice_obj.push(arr[i]);                               
               }

               return notice_obj.join(' ,');
           }  
       });
}
```

and then use the `getItem` function later like this:

```
getItem: function(pid) {
    var $this = $$('.time-line-content .item-content[data-id="'+ pid +'"]');
    var item = {
        id: $this.data('id'),
        nickname: $this.find('.item-header .detail .nickname').html()
    };

    item.propslider = this.getItemImages(pid);

    var output = TM.renderTplById('itemTemplate', item);

    $$('#itemContent').html(output);
}
```

So far my `console.log` gives me json data as I expect. When I call the `getItemImages` function inside the `getItem` function, I don't seem to get any data. Something is wrong with the `getItemImages` function. I am not able to figure out what.

Comment: `getItemImages` is an asynchronous call, you can't simply `return`. You need to await the result or use the result within the callback function

Comment: Thank you @santi totally forgot about that
I'll post a solution later

Answer (score 0):

With a little guidance from [Javascript callback functions with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988277/javascript-callback-functions-with-ajax)